# BLPAPI & Bloomberg Swap Manager

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

Any blpapi users, specifically the python API, have any examples/guidance on using the swap manager function?

In excel, we have a formula that access the swap manager, it looks somewhat like this

```
=@BView(BPRICE(BSTRUCTURE(x,y,z,date,date(x,y,z,""()))
```

For the Bloomberg python API, I'm unable to find any documentation on how to call these functions. Any ideas?